# Passing Observable in state on Angular Router

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, observable, angular-routing, angular-router

Using Ionic with Angular 8.

I want send Observable like this:

```
let request: Observable<any> = return this.http.get('some url');
```

from one component to another:

```
this.router.navigate(['confirm'], {state: {req: request}})
```

Bun i get error while i try to route in this component

> DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History',

How i can pass Observable in component when i go to it?

Comment: I recommend to use a service where you store the observable and you inject this service. Don't use the router to pass the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done, because the observable cannot be converted to a string. See the examples in the dodcumentation:

```
this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' }]); 
// is converted to the url 
// --> localhost:4200/heroes;id=15;foo=foo
```

https://angular.io/guide/router#heroes-list-optionally-selecting-a-hero

how would you convert a observable into a simple string? If even possible it would result in a very long url. But then the observable is Javascript code, so it would need to be `evaluated`. This would open the door for attacks to insert malicious code into your application and therefor is strictly forbidden by angular. (the fact, that you use Ionic doesn't change that!)

TLDR: query parameters are not intended for complex logic. Store it in a service, etc and reuse it in both componets